# how to pass multiple list to multiprocessing in python

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

in multiprocessing how to pass the multiple list to the function,
here is my sample code

```
import multiprocessing

def unzip_all_data(data):
    for i in data:
         index=i[0]
         no=i[1]
         item=i[2]
         print(index,no,item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(pool_size)

    list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
    list2=['one','two','three','four','five']
    list3=['apple','orange','banana','grapes','pineapple']

    all_data=zip(list1,list2,list3)
    data=list(all_data)

    pool.map(unzip_all_data,data)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

my expected output is :

1,one,apple

2,two,orange

3,three,banana

4,four,grapes

5,five,pineappple

Answer (score 0):

There is two different issues.

First, you want to actually call `unzip_all_data` somewhere. This is a typo and `pool.map(unzip_all_data,data)` should be written `pool.map(unzip_all_data(data))` instead.

Now that you do call the function, it will print things in the order you intended but return None because your function has no `return`. You need to add one but without more info I don't know what you expect to return there.